# Create EC keys using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, openssl

I'm using Node.js and trying to mimic the functionality of the following openssl command to generate a public key:

```
$> openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out keys
$> openssl ec -in keys -pubout -out pubkey
```

The closest I have is:

```
var ec = crypto.createECDH('prime256v1');
var pub = ec.generateKeys("base64");
```

But this key is far shorter and doesn't work. Any ideas how I could mimic the functionality exactly?

Comment: The key you are creating is shorter because `openssl ecparam ...` uses the domain parameters and *not* the named curve. I'm guessing Node.js is using the named curve. Using domain parameters will likely cause problems later; see [Elliptic Curve Cryptography | Named Curve](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Elliptic_Curve_Cryptography#Named_Curves) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: Thanks, that seems wonky to me :)

Comment: Sorry, how this solved the issue? Does the above node.js lines generate proper EC keys (for use in digital signature method - ECDSA)?